# C# and MS Access database (updating)

Tags: c#, ms-access, ado.net, tableadapter

I created a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application in [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29), created a data source in C# from the my MS Access database 'inspro' on the form I coded for the save button:

```
try
{
    this.Validate();
    this.entitiesBindingSource.EndEdit();
    this.entitiesTableAdapter.Update(this.iNSPRODataSet.Entities);
    MessageBox.Show("Update successful");
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Update failed");
}
```

I get the message box that says "Update successful", but when I check in Access, nothing is updated. How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It could be related to the [EndEdit() bug that has caught many others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686597/ado-net-databinding-bug-bindingsource-endedit-changes-current-position). If it moves the focus, that could be why you're not seeing the save you're expecting.

Another possibility, read the [comments at the bottom of this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171933%28VS.80%29.aspx), it has to do with a copy of the MDF moving to the debug folder, effectively overwriting the changes.

{EDIT} As pointed out by Julien, the second article I mentioned references an MDF (SQL Server), and access would be a MDB, but the theory there is still sound. Check to see if the included file is set to copy to output directory.

Comment: You're right, my answer had nothing to do with the question. I deleted it. BTW, he's using Access, so it's an .mdb file